# how to export a hook local variable from another file along with the component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

i want to use the Aya varriable in app.js (the code below is in a component) but i can't export it as it's local to the function

```
function BasicExample() {
    const [Aya, setAya] = useState({data});
   // code containing modifications to apply to Aya
}
export default BasicExample
```

Comment: You'll need to [lift the state up](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components). Basically define the state in App and pass a handler that does the update to the state down to your child component so it can call it with a new value.

Comment: can you show me how it'd look on my code i ve been tryin it and i think i'm doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

[Lift state up](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components). Basically define the state in App and pass a handler that does the update to the state down to your child component so it can call it with a new value.

In this example I have the main component which renders a child component. In that component is a div that displays the `count` from the parent state, and a button to increment its value. Note that a function (the handler) is written in the parent component, and then a reference to it is passed down into the props of the child component - along with the value.

When the button is clicked the function is called. This updates the state which causes a new render, and the updated state is reflected in the child component by the updated value.

```js
const { Fragment, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Initialise state
  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);

  // A function called `handleClick` that
  // updates the state. This handler is passed down
  // to the child component via its props
  function handleClick() {
    setCount(prev => prev + 1);
  }

  // The child component accepts both the
  // `count` state, and the handler as its props
  return (
    <ChildComponent 
      count={count}
      handleClick={handleClick}
    />
  );

}

// We destructure the count and the (reference to the)
// function from the component's props.
// When the button is clicked it calls the handler.
// Changes to the state are reflected here when the parent
// component re-renders
function ChildComponent({ count, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>{count}</div>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >Increment count
      </button>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```